Async Task running on multiple threads without Task.Run?
I tested the following code:
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

static class Program {
    static TaskCompletionSource tsc;
    static async Task F1(int i) {
        // PART 1
        await tsc.Task;
        // PART 2
        Console.WriteLine($"call: {i}, thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode()}");
    }
    static async Task Main() {
        tsc = new();
        var tasks = new Task[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
        {
            F1(i);
        }
        tsc.SetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("what?!");
        //await Task.Yield();
        Console.WriteLine("done");
    }
}

It was my understanding that calling "F1" (without "await") multiple times would happen on a single thread ("main thread"). The execution would "await" on "PART 1" ("tsc.Task") and return to continue on caller, creating 5 tasks waiting. Them i could set the result of "TaskSourceCompletion" and i would require to call "Task.Yield" to give "idle time" to the execution of the all queued Tasks. If i didnt "Yield", my program would finish without giving time to finish ("PART 2").
But the current code executes like this:
call: 0, thread: 1
call: 3, thread: 21
call: 1, thread: 17
call: 2, thread: 20
what?!
done
call: 4, thread: 19

My understand was if i wanted the code to execute on the "ThreadPool" (or different threads) i needed to call "Task.Run", otherwise the code would queue on current thread and only execute on "idle time" (awaiting something).

But currently it seems that all async Tasks continue execution on different threads, not needed to "Task.Run" for it. Is this correct assumption ?

Is there anyway to force the behavior i expected, that all async Tasks only execute on main thread, only if i give them "idle time" (any posterior await, like: "Task.Yield" or "Task.Delay").



Run the same code in a Winforms app as opposed to a console app.

"It was my understanding that calling "F1" (without "await") multiple times would happen on a single thread ("main thread")." where did you get that from? It depends on the scheduler, which for a console app allows any threadpool thread to continue.

@Charlieface not only any ThreadPool thread, but any thread in general. In Console apps, the await continuations run on whatever thread completed the awaitable.

@Charlieface So it all depends on having a SynchronizationContext ? A console app doesnt have one and it runs the default behaviour thats the tasks run on threadpool ?

Pretty much yeah, that's right.

Keep in mind that Task do not really represents code, just something that may complete in the future. So it would be more correct to say "code after an await may run on the threadpool, depending on the state of the task, the synchronization context, how the awaiter was configured, etc"
